# How can I find the root cause for AWS CloudFormation stack creation failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to install a simple stack using AWS CloudFormation. I create an IAM user and also pass in some script to install Puppet and Git through userdata so that it can be executed by cloudinit.

The problem is for some reason the template fails mid way and the stack creation is rolled back. I am doing this through the management GUI. But it doesn't tell me why it fails. I can see that some of the resources are created and then it fails. Is there a way to look at detailed logs to see what exactly is failing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) for [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) offers an *Events* tab in the stack detail panel, which lists the stack life-cycle events and features a *Reason* column in turn, which contains more details for the errors in case.

This column exposes the `ResourceStatusReason` field of the [StackEvent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_StackEvent.html) data type retrieved via the [DescribeStackEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStackEvents.html) action:

> **ResourceStatusReason** - Success/failure message associated with the resource